# Azure Access Restriction

Tags: azure

We have multiple apps under one service plan and we want to restrict the access to development slots from outside the office, So my question is Can the access restriction rules be configured in one place and applied to all the development apps/slots?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can set it up. To add an access restriction rule to your app, use the menu to open **Network>Access Restrictions** and click on Configure Access Restrictions

From the Access Restrictions UI, you can review the list of access restriction rules defined for your app.

Here is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions)

Comment: Thank you. Can I set it up at the app service plan level? once created I should be able to use the same restriction for other applications under the resource group or app service plan?

Comment: no you cannot set it up the app service plan level. Also resource group is to restrict the access to resources not to restrict accessing site

Comment: So it is application-specific. we should create it for each application separately. is my understanding right?

Comment: yes afaik, you need to handle individually. however you can try the location based restriction https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/location-condition

Comment: Surely will give it a try